# Convert date format yyyy/MM/dd/hh/mm/ss to datetime object in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, date, datetime

I am trying to take a date that I am receiving from a Linux system as a string in the format `yyyy/MM/dd/hh/mm/ss` and I would like to convert it into a datetime PowerShell object. I have tried using the `ParseExact` method but appear to be missing something here because I keep getting the message that the DateTime format is not valid. Maybe I am going about this the wrong way completely. Any suggestions?

```
$DateTimeObject = [datetime]::ParseExact('2018/05/21/14/08/17',"yyyy/MM/dd/hh/mm/ss",$null)
```

> Exception calling "ParseExact" with "3" argument(s): "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + [datetime]::ParseExact('2018/05/21/14/08/17',"yyyy/MM/dd/hh/mm/ss",$n ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FormatException

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your date string has `14` for the hour, which is using 24-hour time. `hh` however only supports hours in the range `01-12`. You need to use an uppercase `HH` instead:

```
$DateTimeObject = [datetime]::ParseExact('2018/05/21/14/08/17',"yyyy/MM/dd/HH/mm/ss",$null)
#                                                                          ^^
```

You can find a list of all valid format codes [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings).

Comment: That was it!  Thank you for taking the time to explain it!

Answer (score 0):

You *could* write your own parsing function:

```
function ConvertTo-DateTime([string] $datetime) {
    $arr = $datetime -split '/'
    return [datetime](($arr[0..2] -join '-'), ($arr[3..5] -join ':') -join ' ')
}
```